Node.js Net server truncates messages chunks to 65536 characters. How to know when the complete message has been sent?
I have several scripts that are concurrently sending requests to the same API server. There is a limit to the number of requests per second I can submit, so I'm trying to centralize the request counting to a local Node.js Net relay server, instead of having each individual script count their own requests. I tried both IPC and TCP.
This is what the server looks like:
const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    console.log('Client connected to server');

    socket.on('data', async (data) => {
        await sleep(1000);
        const parameters = JSON.parse(data);
        const API_data = await fetchDataFromAPI(...parameters); 
        socket.write(JSON.stringify(API_data));
    });
});

The API responses are often very long JSON strings. I wasn't expecting each message to be broken into smaller pieces. I am using this logic in the client to know when the message has been received and continue:
async sendRequest(data) {

  this.client.write(data);

  const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.on('data', data => resolve(data));
  });
  return JSON.parse(response);

}
I get the message across, but I only the first 65536 characters of the JSON string. I was initially using this.client.once('data', but the outcome is the same.
What is the best way to deal with this situation? Do I need to manually add a end of string message? Or use a different system entirely?
